# cart session to save products by size

Tags: php, mysqli, cart

I have this code to save product in cart.
I need to save product and size - quantity x price.
At this momment is storing product name, size, quantity and price, but it display the same row.
If I add 'product1' size M quanity 1, and if I add 'product1' size S quanitity 1, in the cart I get 'product1' size S (the last size added) quantity 1 (but in the tquan I get 2 products).
So how can I make to have for each size of a product, another row.

```
$_SESSION['CART']['order_token']    = $form_token;
        $arrCart['id']              = $pID;
        $arrCart['quantity']    = $_SESSION['CART']['PRODUCT'][$pID]['size']['quantity'] + $_POST['quantity'];
        $chkQuan = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($link, "SELECT quantity FROM table WHERE id = '".$pID."'"));

            $total =$_SESSION['CART']['tquan']+$_POST['quantity'];
            $arrCart['pret']                = $_POST['product_price'];
            $arrCart['size']                = $_POST['size'];
            $_SESSION['CART']['tquan']      = $total;
            $_SESSION['CART']['PRODUCT'][$pID] = $arrCart;
```

And this part is for displaying cart

```
        if(isset($_SESSION['CART']) && $_SESSION['CART']!='') 
        { 

            $endsumm = '';
            $product_total_price = '';
            foreach($_SESSION['CART']['PRODUCT'] as $pID=>$pArr)
            {
                $prod = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id='".$pID."'"));
                $product_total_price = $pArr['quantity']*$pArr['pret'];
                $endsumm += $pArr['quantity']*$pArr['pret'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Before inserting product in the cart, you should check that product is already in the cart or not.

- Here in your case you should check for the **productid** as well as **size** is available in the cart or not. 
  If any one or both condition is not true then insert that product into the cart.
  Otherwise update your cart.

```
                $total =$_SESSION['CART']['tquan']+$_POST['quantity'];
       $arrCart['pret']= $_POST['product_price'];
       $arrCart['size']= $_POST['size'];
    $_SESSION['CART']['tquan'] = $total;
    $_SESSION['CART']['PRODUCT'][$pID] = $arrCart

if(!in_array($pID, array_map(function($id){return $id[$pID];}, $_SESSION['CART']))){

          if(!in_array($_POST['size'], array_map(function($size){return $size['size'];}, $_SESSION['CART']))){

//Here insert the product into the cart as you were inserted in the question

     }


}
```

Comment: Thank you for your text answear. If I knew how to do that, I would do it. So I kindely ask you to help me edit the code I succed puting up to work.

But also I think there must be another way. It should be abble to add to cart product and size and list them right. Maybe I insert data right but I didnt row it right... I have not much experience with sessions
Thx

Comment: Ok. I will try it. :)